# Getting an error message when using 'cypress-testrail-reporter' plugin to integrate TestRail and Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress, testrail

The setup I have in my cypress.json file is:

```
 "reporter": "../../../../node_modules/cypress-testrail-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
     "host": "https://mydomain.testrail.io/",
    "domain": "mydomain.testrail.io",
    "username": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "password": "API password",
    "projectId": 1,
    "suiteId": 1,
    "runName": "Currency Test"
  }
```

When the Cypress tests are run, the status of the testcases do get updated in the TestRail. However, I see this error at the end.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split').

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can I suggest you put something inside the test?

Comment: I do have the code "cy.get('button').should('exist')" inside the test.